# How can I properly use CGImageProperties.h on iOS 4+

Tags: iphone, image, ios4, metadata

For my university project I need to obtain various information about a photo on the iOS platform to determine if the room the user is in contains the correct lighting conditions. Data I need includes ISO, exposure, brightness.

I noticed these data values are found in this manner: `CGImageProperties.h` -> `kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary` -> `kCGImagePropertyExifISOSpeedRatings`

I do not have much formal experience in iOS development so I was wondering if anyone had further documentation for this header file or sample code, even at the most basic level, that I can digest and learn how to properly use `CGImageProperties.h`. Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add the ImageIO framework to your app.

Then in your header file:

```
#import <ImageIO/CGImageProperties.h>
```

Comment: do not forget to add ImageIO.framework, CoreFoundation.framework and CoreGraphics.framework in your target->Build Phases->Link with binary libraries tab